# Filtering Foreign key choices in Django serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model that looks like the code below. At the moment, when I am using django rest framework to create a new menu instance, the dish column contains options created by all users on the platform.
How should I go about filtering the dish column so it only has options created by the user?
Should I be doing it in the views or serializer?

Thank you for the response in advance.

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/post_image',
                              default='static/images/post_image/default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        return obj.image.url


class Menu(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    dish = models.ManyToManyField(Dish)
    price = models.SmallIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10000)], default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'
```

This is how I ended up doing it for those who have the same problems in the future.

```py
class UserDishForeignKey(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        return Dish.objects.filter(user=user)


class MenuCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dish = UserDishForeignKey(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'dish', 'price', ]
        read_only_fields = ['user', ]

    def get_user(self, obj):
        return str(obj.user.username)
```

Comment: I would suggest doing it in the view by modifying the `get_queryset()` method using the answer by Tuomo below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an `user` object, you can get all dishes associated to that `user` like this:

```
user.dish_set
```

If you want to find all menu's that are having particular menus by dish's owner. That can be done like

```
Menu.objects.filter(dish__user=user)
```

Placement of this depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to validate the input, placement should be in serializer

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserDishForeignKey(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        return Dish.objects.filter(user=user)


class MenuCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dish = UserDishForeignKey(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'dish', 'price', ]
        read_only_fields = ['user', ]

    def get_user(self, obj):
        return str(obj.user.username)
```